# ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis (FK)

Tags: sql, oracle, command, foreign-keys

```
alter table booking 
add constraint fk_customer_id 
foreign key customer_id 
references customer (customer_id);
```

what is the problem, can somebody help?

Comment: It's indicating you need to add a left parenthesis to "FK"; since "fk" only appears once, it must be before "fk_customer_id" where the left paren is expected. See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_add_constraint_syntax_example.htm

Comment: I'm not an Oracle-head, but does foreign key need to be uppercased to  FOREIGN KEY?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, register not important

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, no it does not

Answer (score 4):

Try parens around the field name

```
alter table booking 
add constraint fk_customer_id 
foreign key (customer_id) 
references customer (customer_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need brackets around the source field name, and around the entire constraint as part of the ***alter table add (..your addition here...)*** syntax

```
alter table booking add
( 
   constraint fk_customer_id 
   foreign key (customer_id )
   references customer (customer_id)
);
```

Revise that - the outer brackets are only required if adding more than one item, so give the correct answer to andraemc but be aware of the possible need for outer brackets. I always stick 'em in to keep the style consistent, and so I don't ever forget to!